# How to calculate probability of each country with total death in excel formula?

Tags: excel-formula

How to do this sum: each country, calculate the probability of death using excel formula.

[image]

Comment: `E2/C2*100` and pulled down?

Comment: Why not total case / total death * 100? Can i know why you use population instead?

Comment: Do you mean probability of death by natural disaster? What have you tried yourself?

Comment: Why are you asking _me_, what _you_ are after. We are just translating general problems into excel-formula-language. People come here with a concrete problem, which they should explain with maximal possible clarity. Your one-liner doesn't fit to this and the screenshot doesn't provide any clue on what you want to accomplish. Also it is expected from the asking person to show attempts on solving the problem.

Comment: You dont have to be rude. Thank you

Comment: mors certa: 1, Excel or not.

Answer (score 0):

Probability of death excluding death by natural causes:

```
=(D2-E2)/C2
```

Format as `%`.

[image: Percentage format]

Answer (score 0):

Probability of death does not depend on citizenship or location - and it equals `100%`, unfortunately.

The formula you are looking for is `1` or `=1`, you can format it using `%`.

Other answers are only shooting. It seems like the correct question should include - somehow - the cause of death (otherwise it makes no sense to have "natural" and "disasters" separately) and some statement about the time interval.